# JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<> Creating Null Items in Collections

Tags: c#, blazor

I am encountering an issue when I am making a call from my Blazor WebAssembly Service Class to my API. The object being returned has a collection of items which is correct at the API but when its deserialized the collection has Null entries.

SERVICE CLASS

```
var response = await _publicClient.Client.GetAsync($"Recipe/GetByNameForUser/{userName}/{name}");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var recipe =  await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Recipe>
                        (await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });

                        return recipe;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error deserializing result in GetByNameForUserAsync: name {name}");
                    }
                }
```

API Controller

```
try
            {
                var result = await _repository.GetByNameForUserAsync(name, userName);

                if (result == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                return Ok(result);
            }
```

Repository

```
var recipe = await _dataContext.Recipes.Include(a => a.RecipeCategory)
                                                 .Include(a => a.SocialMedia)
                                                 .Include(a => a.TimeTemps)
                                                    .ThenInclude(a => a.TimeDuration)
                                                 .Include(a => a.TimeTemps)
                                                    .ThenInclude(a => a.TemperatureUnit)
                                                 .Include(a => a.MeasuredIngredients)
                                                 .Include(a => a.RecipeSteps)
                                                 .Include(a => a.RecipeFuels)
                                                    .ThenInclude(a => a.Fuel)
                                                 .Where(a => a.UserName == userName)
                                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Name == name);

                return recipe;
```

Here are the results at each level

Repository
Here you can see that the Recipe Steps returned is 2 which is expected

[image]

Controller
Here you can see again the Recipe steps being returned from api is 2 which is expected

[image]

Service Class
Here is the issue. When the result is deserialized there are now 4 items in the collection and 2 of them are Null.

[image]

What is going on here? Why is the collection having null entries added?

Here is the json response coming back from the API via PostMan

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "userId": "aacc90e3-c1cf-4f04-8bab-3a3498e84904",
    "userName": "BBQFriend",
    "name": "Update Name",
    "description": "is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    "isPublic": true,
    "recipeCategoryId": 11,
    "recipeCategory": {
        "id": 11,
        "displayValue": "Appetizer"
    },
    "socialMediaId": 3,
    "socialMedia": {
        "id": 3,
        "facebookURL": "123",
        "instagramURL": "123",
        "tikTokURL": "123",
        "pinterestURL": "123",
        "youTubeURL": "123",
        "website": "123"
    },
    "timeTemps": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "temperature": 222.00,
            "temperatureUnitId": 2,
            "temperatureUnit": {
                "id": 2,
                "displayValue": "Celsius",
                "symbol": "C"
            },
            "cookTime": 221.00,
            "timeDurationId": 2,
            "timeDuration": {
                "id": 2,
                "displayValue": "Minutes",
                "symbol": "min"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "temperature": 341.00,
            "temperatureUnitId": 2,
            "temperatureUnit": {
                "id": 2,
                "displayValue": "Celsius",
                "symbol": "C"
            },
            "cookTime": 4323.00,
            "timeDurationId": 2,
            "timeDuration": {
                "id": 2,
                "displayValue": "Minutes",
                "symbol": "min"
            }
        }
    ],
    "recipeFuels": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fuelId": 1,
            "fuel": {
                "id": 1,
                "displayValue": "Bear Mountain BBQ Apple",
                "description": null,
                "fuelType": null,
                "fuelTypeId": 1,
                "createdBy": "aacc90e3-c1cf-4f04-8bab-3a3498e84904",
                "createdDate": "2022-03-17T10:41:30.3362051",
                "lastModifiedBy": null,
                "lastModifiedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "measuredIngredients": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "amount": 1.00,
            "measurementTypeId": 3,
            "measurementType": null,
            "ingredientId": 6,
            "ingredient": null,
            "useId": 1,
            "use": null
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "amount": 1.00,
            "measurementTypeId": 2,
            "measurementType": null,
            "ingredientId": 7,
            "ingredient": null,
            "useId": null,
            "use": null
        }
    ],
    "recipeSteps": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "asdfas",
            "description": "asdfasdf"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "adsfas",
            "description": "asdfasdf"
        }
    ],
    "createdBy": "aacc90e3-c1cf-4f04-8bab-3a3498e84904",
    "createdDate": "2022-03-17T11:26:06.2535611",
    "lastModifiedBy": "aacc90e3-c1cf-4f04-8bab-3a3498e84904",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2022-03-18T13:01:23.5958959"
}
```

Recipe Model

```
public class Recipe
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
        

        public int RecipeCategoryId { get; set; }
        public RecipeCategory RecipeCategory { get; set; }
        public int SocialMediaId { get; set; }
        public SocialMedia SocialMedia { get; set; }
        
        public virtual List<TimeTemp> TimeTemps { get; set; }
        public virtual List<RecipeFuel> RecipeFuels{ get;set; }
        public List<MeasuredIngredient> MeasuredIngredients { get; set; }
        public List<RecipeStep> RecipeSteps { get; set; }

        
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public Recipe()
        {
            MeasuredIngredients = new List<MeasuredIngredient>();
            RecipeSteps = new List<RecipeStep>();
            SocialMedia = new SocialMedia();
            RecipeFuels = new List<RecipeFuel>();
            TimeTemps = new List<TimeTemp>();
            IsPublic = true;
        }
    }
```

There is something really funky going on with the deserilize.  Why are ALL the collections showing as System.Generic.List and not the actual collection it self.  Also to note that EVERY collection on the Recipe is showing 4 Items.  If there is 1 real item there are 3 null.  If there are 2 items 2 show null.

[image]

Here is the value that i get from the ( I changed the description to a shorter description)

```
await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

'{"id":1,"userId":"aacc90e3-c1cf-4f04-8bab-3a3498e84904","userName":"BBQFriend","name":"Update Name","description":"Just a standard decsription with no characters","isPublic":true,"recipeCategoryId":11,"recipeCategory":{"id":11,"displayValue":"Appetizer"},"socialMediaId":3,"socialMedia":{"id":3,"facebookURL":"123","instagramURL":"123","tikTokURL":"123","pinterestURL":"123","youTubeURL":"123","website":"123"},"timeTemps":[{"id":1,"temperature":222.00,"temperatureUnitId":2,"temperatureUnit":{"id":…,"measurementTypeId":3,"measurementType":null,"ingredientId":6,"ingredient":null,"useId":1,"use":null},{"id":6,"amount":1.00,"measurementTypeId":2,"measurementType":null,"ingredientId":7,"ingredient":null,"useId":null,"use":null}],"recipeSteps":[{"id":1,"title":"asdfas","description":"asdfasdf"}],"createdBy":"aacc90e3-c1cf-4f04-8bab-3a3498e84904","createdDate":"2022-03-17T11:26:06.2535611","lastModifiedBy":"aacc90e3-c1cf-4f04-8bab-3a3498e84904","lastModifiedDate":"2022-03-19T11:40:37.2096807"}'
```

Comment: please post whats really in response.Content as string. thx

Comment: I went ahead and updated that

Comment: thats interesting. the json is allright, so it can only be a weird deserialization option or your Recipe class doing something strange. if i had to debug it, i would, to prevent race condition as a cause, first try what @Serge answered. if that does not help, i think you should try a different deserializer, just to see if the json is bugged, and if that does not work, your recipe class has some issues. what type are you deserializing that property into, a List<Step> or a Collection Class, or something? also, i would try to rule out if its also occurung when you are NOT debugging

Comment: I went ahead and tried the Newton deserializer and it is the same thing.

Comment: Henk i am sharing everything that i am seeing locally when debugging.  I have shown all aspects including photos, models etc.  Provided valid JSON responses from the API via postman as well as the response i see from response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().   There are tons of details listed above.  Im not sure why it was down voted and requested to be closed due to lack of details...

Answer (score 1):

you are using too many awaits. Your code should be like this. I tested this code in Visual studio and everytning is working properly.

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
    try
    {
  var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                      
   return  System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Recipe>(json);
   }
```

I was using these classes. Please notice that I don't have a special constructor to init lists. I think this is what is causing your bugs.

```
public partial class Recipe
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("userId")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("userName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("isPublic")]
    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("recipeCategoryId")]
    public long RecipeCategoryId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("recipeCategory")]
    public RecipeCategory RecipeCategory { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("socialMediaId")]
    public long SocialMediaId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("socialMedia")]
    public SocialMedia SocialMedia { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("timeTemps")]
    public List<TimeTemp> TimeTemps { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("recipeFuels")]
    public List<RecipeFuel> RecipeFuels { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("measuredIngredients")]
    public List<MeasuredIngredient> MeasuredIngredients { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("recipeSteps")]
    public List<RecipeStep> RecipeSteps { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("createdBy")]
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("createdDate")]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("lastModifiedBy")]
    public Guid LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("lastModifiedDate")]
    public DateTimeOffset LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

public partial class MeasuredIngredient
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("amount")]
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("measurementTypeId")]
    public long MeasurementTypeId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("measurementType")]
    public object MeasurementType { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("ingredientId")]
    public long IngredientId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("ingredient")]
    public object Ingredient { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("useId")]
    public long? UseId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("use")]
    public object Use { get; set; }
}

public partial class RecipeCategory
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("displayValue")]
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }
}

public partial class RecipeFuel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("fuelId")]
    public long FuelId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("fuel")]
    public Fuel Fuel { get; set; }
}

public partial class Fuel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("displayValue")]
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("description")]
    public object Description { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("fuelType")]
    public object FuelType { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("fuelTypeId")]
    public long FuelTypeId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("createdBy")]
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("createdDate")]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("lastModifiedBy")]
    public object LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("lastModifiedDate")]
    public DateTimeOffset LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

public partial class RecipeStep
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public partial class SocialMedia
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("facebookURL")]
    public string FacebookUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("instagramURL")]
    public string InstagramUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("tikTokURL")]
    public string TikTokUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("pinterestURL")]
    public string PinterestUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("youTubeURL")]
    public string YouTubeUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("website")]
    public string Website { get; set; }
}

public partial class TimeTemp
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("temperature")]
    public double Temperature { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("temperatureUnitId")]
    public long TemperatureUnitId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("temperatureUnit")]
    public TemperatureUnit TemperatureUnit { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("cookTime")]
    public double CookTime { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("timeDurationId")]
    public long TimeDurationId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("timeDuration")]
    public TemperatureUnit TimeDuration { get; set; }
}

public partial class TemperatureUnit
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("displayValue")]
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it still has 4 entires with 2 of them being null.  This did not fix it

Comment: Post your Recipe class pls

Comment: @JoeyD Post your Recipe class pls . I tested you json and everything is working properly. So or json is differetnt or Recipe class is different.

Comment: Posted my Recipe model

Comment: i think maybe that constructor of the Recipe class kills it somehow, can you remove that?

Comment: I removed the constructor and its still the same thing

Comment: @JoeyD I added  your constructor and everything is still working properly. Did you use my model?

Comment: Why the partial classes?

Comment: @JoeyD It doesn't matter, it works only for compilation.

Comment: @JoeyD I would check in debugger json that you are getting here  var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); This is the  only place  you can cath a bug, json you posted is deserialized properly, so it is different from origional

Comment: I am still getting the same thing.  The Collection is showing as a System.Collections.Generic.List<BBQFriend.Models.RecipeSteps>.   Its almost like its showing the type and not the actual collection.  If i do recipe.RecipeSteps.count it comes back as 1 which is correct.  But i cant do anything else with that property

Comment: @JoeyD recipe.RecipeSteps.count  should be 2 according to json you posted

Comment: Yeah i had deleted one in testing to see if having 1 vs 2 was making a difference.  I posted above the response from the ReadAsStringAsync()

Comment: i created test models using the ones you have above and its still the same thing.  Serge can you screen shot what the RecipeSteps property looks like when you debug and mouse over like i did above with the highlighted System.Collections.Generic.List<BBQFriend.Models etc.   I am curious to see how yours looks like

Comment: @JoeyD the last json you just posted is not valid. Can you post the real one pls?

Comment: Serge that is the value i get from the response.content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Comment: I changed the List<RecipeStep> to IEnumerable<RecipeStep> and it was the same issue.  When i changed it to RecipeStep[] however it did show only 1 RecipeStep as expecting.

Comment: @Serge i went ahead and change the decription to make it shorter and have posted what the string is from the Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Answer (score 0):

Use **PropertyNameCaseInsensitive** options

```
@code {
    public List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var response = await _http.GetAsync("Customers/GetAll");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using (var reponseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
                customers = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Customer>>(reponseStream, options);
            }
        }
    }
}
```